# Kivy and external event loop

Tags: python, kivy

I'd like to develop a remote controlled framework for running apps based on Kivy. The idea is to use [PodSixNet](https://github.com/chr15m/PodSixNet) (or a similar network layer for client-server communication) to remotely start/control/stop Kivy apps. This is based on running an external event loop (for network events), but how would I take the event loop of whatever Kivy app I want to run from Kivy's responsibility?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from PodSixNet.Connection import connection, ConnectionListener

class App1(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='hello world 1')

class App2(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='hello world 2')

class Client(ConnectionListener):
    def __init__(self, *kargs, **kwargs):
        ConnectionListener.__init__(self, *kargs, **kwargs)
        self.Connect((kwargs['host'], kwargs['port']))
        self.current_app = App1()
        self.current_app.run()

    def Network_switchGame(self, data):
        """Gets triggered if appropriate message is sent from server"""
        if isinstance(self.current_game, App1):
            self.current_app.stop()
            self.current_app = App2()
        else:
            self.current_app.stop()
            self.current_app = App1()
        self.current_app.run()

    def Loop(self):
        """This function takes care of network events, and app events
        (if there is a valid app)"""
        connection.Pump()
        self.Pump()

        if self.current_game:
            # this should run the Kivy app's event loop
            self.current_game.events()

host, port = sys.argv[1].split(":")
c = Client(host=host, port=int(port))
while 1:
    c.Loop()
```

I'd like to run separate apps because they will have different logics, and later new apps should be added without much trouble.
If it matters: this will eventually run on a Raspberry Pi (and for development on a Mac).

**Edit: Potential solution?**

OK, it seems I can nest apps like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock

class OutsideApp(App):
    current_app = ObjectProperty(None)
    elapsed = NumericProperty(0)
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60)
        self.current_app = App1()
        self.current_app.run()
        return Button(text='fff 1')

    def update(self, dt):
        self.elapsed += dt
        if self.elapsed > 3:
            self.elapsed = 0
            if self.current_app:
                self.current_app.stop()
            if isinstance(self.current_app, App1):
                self.current_app = App2()
            else:
                self.current_app = App1()
            self.current_app.run()


class App1(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='hello world 1')

class App2(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='hello world 2')

oa = OutsideApp()
oa.run()
```

Is this how it should be done?

Comment: For running Kivy's event loop manually, look at `kivy.base.runTouchApp` which includes some information about doing so.

Comment: Is there more documentation than [this](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.base.html#kivy.base.runTouchApp)? The only other reference I have found is [this google group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/8YV6dou14uY), but it's not detailed either. Looking at the source for `kivy.App.run()` suggests I'd have to copy the whole creation sequence before `runTouchApp()`?
Finally, is there a reason not to nest apps as in the edit?

Comment: runTouchApp doesn't need all the app structure. I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but if your edit does what you want then that's fine.